# Observable only emits one value?

Tags: observable, rx-swift

I'm new in RxSwift, I have this code snipped that print in my console:

next(second value)

completed

but I was expecting this result:

next(first value)

next(second  value)

completed

why is not reacting twice the subscribe? I understand that in react, the observable emits and trigger the subscribe evert time that the variable that we are observing change but the code is not showing this. Do I misunderstand the concept?

```
var mutableString = "first value"
mutableString = "second value"

var stringObservable: Observable<String> = Observable.of(mutableString)
        
stringObservable.subscribe { event in
    print(event)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the program runs, it goes through each line of code step by step. So first it creates the variable `mutableString` and assigns "first value" to it. Then in the next line it assigns "second value" to the variable.

Then it creates the variable `stringObservable` of type `Observable<String>` and assigns `Observable.of(mutableString)` to it, since mutableString contains "second value", that is what the value inside the Observable is assigned.

Note that the Observable has it's own variable inside it so changing the value of `mutableString` will not affect the Observable.

To get the output you are looking for, you need to pass all of the values you want the Observable to output at the time of creation, like this:

```
let stringObservable: Observable<String> = Observable.of("first value", "second value")
stringObservable.subscribe { event in
    print(event)
}
```

Another option would be to create an Observable that has a function which outputs the values:

```
func makeObservable(from array: [String]) -> Observable<String> {
    Observable<String>.create { observer in
        for each in array {
            observer.onNext(each)
        }
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

This is basically how Observable's `of(_:)` operator is implemented. Every time the resulting Observable is subscribed to, it will run the closure that was passed into the `create` function causing it to emit the two values (and the completed event) again.

Comment: Thanks for the response now I see the issue I was modifying the variable not the observable itself. One think more there is a way to add element to an observable but not in the create or the of, I mean inicializace the observes with some values in the of or create and later in the code add more values doing something like stringObservable.value = "third element" or StringObservable.onNext("third element"), I see some people using a Variable later they cast with asObservable() and can do thing like StringObservable.value = "third element" maybe is not allowed with Observables?

Comment: You could do that with a `Subject` and call `asObservable()` on the subject to get an observable from it (`Variable` was a form of subject which is not deprecated.) Subjects provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use. Better would be to establish an invariant that will cause the Observable to emit values than have something that emits for no particular reason.